# SysListView32: SendMessage с параметром LVM_GETITEMTEXT всегда возвращает 0

Tags: c#, winapi, listview

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(
    [In, Optional] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpClassName,
    [In, Optional] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(
    [In, Optional] IntPtr hwndParent,
    [In, Optional] IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
    [In, Optional] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszClass,
    [In, Optional] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(
    [In] IntPtr hWnd,
    [In] uint Msg,
    [In] IntPtr wParam,
    [In] IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(
    [In] IntPtr hProcess,
    [In, Optional] IntPtr lpAddress,
    [In] uint dwSize,
    [In] uint flAllocationType,
    [In] uint flProtect);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(
    [In] IntPtr hProcess,
    [In] IntPtr lpAddress,
    [In] uint dwSize,
    [In] uint dwFreeType);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
    [In] IntPtr hProcess,
    [In] IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    [In] ref LVITEM lpBuffer,
    [In] int nSize,
    out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
    [In] IntPtr hProcess,
    [In] IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    [In] IntPtr lpBuffer,
    [In] uint nSize,
    [Out] uint lpNumberOfBytesRead);

const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
const int LVM_GETITEMCOUNT = LVM_FIRST + 4;
const int LVM_GETITEMTEXT = LVM_FIRST + 115;
const int HDM_GETITEMCOUNT = 0x1200;
const int MAX_LVITEM_TEXT_SIZE = 512;

const int MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;
const int PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04;
const int MEM_RELEASE = 0x00008000;

const int LVIF_TEXT = 0x0001;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct LVITEM {
    public uint mask;
    public int iItem;
    public int iSubItem;
    public uint state;
    public uint stateMask;
    public IntPtr pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public int iIndent;
    public int iGroupId;
    public uint cColumns;
    public IntPtr puColumns;
    public IntPtr piColFmt;
    public int iGroup;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {

    // ...

    const int lvItemSize = 76;

    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "<Window Name>");
    IntPtr hSysListView32 = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", null);
    IntPtr hSysHeader32 = FindWindowEx(hSysListView32, IntPtr.Zero, "SysHeader32", "");

    if (hSysHeader32 == IntPtr.Zero) return;

    int itemsCount = (int)SendMessage(hSysListView32, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    int colCount = (int)SendMessage(hSysHeader32, HDM_GETITEMCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

    Console.Write("Items: {0}\nColumns: {1}\n", itemsCount, colCount);

    IntPtr lpLocalBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(MAX_LVITEM_TEXT_SIZE);
    IntPtr lpLvItem = VirtualAllocEx(proc.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, lvItemSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    IntPtr lpText = VirtualAllocEx(proc.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, MAX_LVITEM_TEXT_SIZE, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    LVITEM lvItem = new LVITEM();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {

        Console.Write("\n\n".PadLeft(50, '-') + "\n".PadLeft(50, '-'));

        for (int j = 0; i < colCount; j++) {

            lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
            lvItem.iSubItem = j;
            lvItem.iItem = i;
            lvItem.pszText = lpText;
            lvItem.cchTextMax = MAX_LVITEM_TEXT_SIZE;

            WriteProcessMemory(proc.Handle, lpLvItem, ref lvItem, lvItemSize, out uint written);
            int symbolsCount = (int)SendMessage(hSysListView32, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, (IntPtr)i, lpLvItem);

            if (symbolsCount > 0) {
                ReadProcessMemory(proc.Handle, lpText, lpLocalBuffer, MAX_LVITEM_TEXT_SIZE, 0);
                Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(lpLocalBuffer));
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

    if (lpLocalBuffer != IntPtr.Zero)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpLocalBuffer);
    if (lpLvItem != IntPtr.Zero)
        VirtualFreeEx(proc.Handle, lpLvItem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    if (lpText != IntPtr.Zero)
        VirtualFreeEx(proc.Handle, lpText, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    // ...
}
```

Данный код предназначен для получения содержимого SysListView32. Значения каждого элемента в каждом столбце. Подскажите, какая ошибка допущена здесь, если SendMessage с параметром LVM_GETITEMTEXT всегда возвращает 0.

Проблем с самим окном быть не может.

Comment: Каким образом вы узнали размер `lvItemSize`? А вообще лучше использовать UI Automation,

Comment: UI Automation нет в .NET 2.0. Размер `lvItemSize`? Ну во-первых посчитать можно глядя на типы полей структуры, а во-вторых, посмотреть через `Marshal.SizeOf` (используя unsafe).

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, в каком режиме находится ListView: Details, List, Tile...

Comment: В режиме "List"

Comment: Есть аналогичный рабочий код на C++: https://pastebin.com/VgaFkQ33. Просто хочу перевести на С#.

Comment: Ваш код вроде рабочий, по крайней мере, если из 32-битного приложения обращаться к 32-битному. Только нет проверки возвращаемых значений VirtualAlloc и WriteProcessMemory.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Проблема действительно было в том, что обращался к 32-битному приложению из 64-битного. Поменял целевую платформу на x86 и всё заработало.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight А можно ли сделать так, чтобы мы обращались из 64-битного в 32-битное приложение? Т.е. не менять целевую платформу моего проекта.

Comment: Для начала, избавиться от IntPtr в структуре и использовать вместо него Int32. Я не знаю, что у вас значит зашитый в коде размер `const int lvItemSize = 76;` - если он посчитан с учетом 64-битного указателя, нужно пересчитать на 32-битный. Потом уже отлаживать то ,что получится (возможно, еще какие-то ошибки вылезут).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Вы предлагаете заменить IntPtr на Int32 в LVItem? Ну да. Тогда размер будет 60 - какой и должен быть. Я это пробовал. Не помогло.

Comment: Да этот размер по сути и не важен. Должно работать и так. Если это не работает, ищите ошибку в чем-то другом (права доступа у дескриптора процесса, например). Проверяйте возвращаемые значения функций и вызывайте GetLastError в случае ошибки.

Comment: А нет. Замена IntPtr на Int32 исправила положение. Теперь и на x64 работает) Видимо когда я это пробовал были другие ошибки

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Оформите ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогам обсуждения в комментариях:

1. Приведенный в вопросе код работает, если обращаться к 32-битному приложению из 32-битного (или к 64-битному из 64-битного).
2. Если нужно обращаться к приложению другой битности, нужно избавиться от типа *IntPtr* в структуре *LVITEM* и заменить его на тип, который ожидает целевое приложение: например, *Int32*, если целевое приложение 32-битное.

Дело в том, что размер типа *IntPtr* зависит от целевой архитектуры выполняющегося приложения; если данные передаются в приложение с другой целевой архитектурой, они будут с его точки зрения некорректны. Поэтому нужно использовать тип с фиксированным размером.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, в строке `for (int j = 0; i < colCount; j++) {`
i заменить на j, иначе внутренний цикл никогда не закончится.

Во-вторых, проверить на согласованность ANSI / UNICODE. Я вижу Вы за LVM_GETITEMTEXT закрепили код LVM_GETITEMTEXTW (LVM_FIRST+0x115), т.е. UNICODE-вариант строки должен приходить. Для этого надо вызывать SendMessageW(), а не SendMessageA(). Проверьте, во что у Вас преобразуется SendMessage(): в SendMessageW() или в SendMessageA(). Я никогда не пробовал ANSI-функцией требовать UNICODE-строку и наоборот и не знаю,будет выполнено корректное преобразование или возвращена ошибка. Может с этим связана проблема.

Comment: DllImport CharSet = CharSet.Auto соответствует Unicode на ОС, поддерживающих его, так что должна вызываться SendMessageW

Comment: Верно. Предложенные изменения результатов не дали (ну кроме исправления опечатки с i на j).

Comment: Стиль LVS_OWNERDATA часом не выставлен? При стиле List View LVS_OWNERDATA сообщение LVM_GETITEMTEXT не поддерживается. Для таблицы, я так понимаю, должен также быть выставлен стиль LVS_REPORT

Comment: В комментариях к вопросу есть ссылка на пример аналогичного кода только на C++. Он работает.

Comment: Я же написал, что проблем с окном быть не может